# Inserir um volume grande de dados no sql server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Baixei uma lista de cidades na internet. São mais de 5.000 municípios. Tentei um Insert simples e não consegui. Excedeu o número máximo de 1000 registros. Aí tentei com Bulk, mas não sei se fiz certo ou não, o fato é que dá erro. Meu bulk está assim:

```
BULK INSERT CIDADE 
FROM 'C:\Lixo\Cidade_Brasil.txt'
```

E meu txt está nesse formato:

```
(1, 'Afonso Cláudio', 8),
(2, 'Água Doce do Norte', 8),
(3, 'Águia Branca', 8),
(4, 'Alegre', 8),
(5, 'Alfredo Chaves', 8),
(6, 'Alto Rio Novo', 8),
(7, 'Anchieta', 8),
(8, 'Apiacá', 8),
(9, 'Aracruz', 8),
(10, 'Atilio Vivacqua', 8),
(11, 'Baixo Guandu', 8),
(12, 'Barra de São Francisco', 8),
(13, 'Boa Esperança', 8),
......;
```

E essa é a mensagem de erro:

> Mensagem 4832, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 3 Carregamento em massa: fim
>   de arquivo inesperado no arquivo de dados. Mensagem 7399, Nível 16,
>   Estado 1, Linha 3 O provedor do OLE DB "BULK" para o servidor
>   vinculado "(null)" reportou um erro. O provedor não forneceu
>   informações sobre o erro. Mensagem 7330, Nível 16, Estado 2, Linha 3
>   Não é possível buscar uma linha no provedor do OLE DB "BULK" para o
>   servidor vinculado "(null)".

Comment: Os nomes que tem aspas simples, por exemplo `olho d'agua` estão escapados?

Comment: Nem pensei nisso. Vou corrigí-los todos. Mas a sintaxe do bulk é essa mesma?

Comment: Então, voltando ao seu exemplo, olho d``agua está assim: `(161, 'Olho d``Água das Flores', 2),`, sem aspas e sim com "crase" e percebi está assim para todos.

Answer (score 2):

Criei a tabela MUNICIPIOS:

```
CREATE TABLE MUNICIPIOS (
   id int,
   dscidade varchar(35),
   estado varchar(2))
```

Preparei o arquivo de importação:

```
  1,Abadia de Goiás,GO;
  2,Abadia dos Dourados,MG;
  3,Abadiânia,GO;
  4,Abaeté,MG;
  5,Abaetetuba,PA;
  6,Abaiara,CE;
  7,Abaíra,BA;
  8,Abaré,BA;
  9,Alvorada d'Oeste,RO;
 10,Abdon Batista,SC;
 11,Abelardo Luz,SC;
 12,Alta Floresta d'Oeste,RO;
 13,Abre-Campo,MG;
 14,Abreu e Lima,PE;
```

Note que tenho campos com ', mas isso não causará problemas.

Meu script de importação para esse arquivo será assim:

```
BULK INSERT MUNICIPIOS
FROM 'C:\TEMP\MUNICIPIOS.TXT'
WITH
 ( ROWTERMINATOR = ';',  
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   LASTROW = 14 )
```

Eu especifico qual é o separador de registros, qual o separador de colunas e
quantas linhas tem o arquivo de importação.

Comment: Amanhã ao chegar na empresa, vou tentar essa abordagem com essas especificações.

Comment: Não consegui fazer funcionar conforme exemplo do colega ReginaldoRigo.

Comment: @pnet Qual é erro que você esta recebendo?

Comment: Creio que tem a ver com nomes de cidades que possuem apóstrofe na sua composição. Tentei de outra forma, sem o bulk e não funcionou. Vou fazer outro post sobre essa nova abordagem.

Comment: Veja que no exemplo eu deixei cidades com o apostrofes para testar isso. No caso do exemplo eu teria problemas com a virgula ou o ponto e virgula porque estão sendo usado como marcadores e não com outro carácter. Eu testei no SQLServer 2012 e funcionou sem problemas tal como esta no exemplo.

Comment: Então Reginaldo, creio que o problema está aí. Tentei o bulk com três registros apenas e não foi. Bem, como eu havia necessidade, baixei da net um BD(.dpk), restaurei no meu server, e importei os dados dessa tabela para a minha tabela. Mas ainda vou testar com bulk a questão.

Comment: É estranho porque aqui funciona normal,  se eu insiro os 14 registros do exemplo ou os 5570 da listagem completa.  Posta aí o erro que você esta recebendo.